# Check if entered from another page using jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am creating a wordpress theme which uses a scrollto effect using jquery.

Everything works great untill you enter the page with the hashed url.

For instance:

http://www.domain.com/#contact

It will just go to the bottom of the page.

This only happens in firefox and not any other browser... Even IE works :D

Anyway.

As i said everything works 100% untill you come in from another page.

If i remove the javascript for the scrolling then it goes to the relevant div.id but when i add the code back it stops working.

Also this only happens to the destinations near the bottom of the page.

Ive tried loading the code within the footer instead of header incase its reading the jquery before the the divs have been created from wordpress but this is no good. It does not work.

Here is the jquery i have created.

```
jQuery(function(){

/***************************************************
        VERTICAL SCROLLING
***************************************************/
    jQuery('a#ublblogback').click(function(){ parent.history.back(); return false;});
    jQuery('#main a, a.internal, a.da-link,  #menu_nav a, .footer_inner a, #footerinternal').click(function(e){

        if (!jQuery(this).hasClass("thisisabloglink")) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        jQuery('div#main ul li:last-child').find('a').css('background','none');

        var $anchor = jQuery(this);
        var $section = jQuery($anchor.attr('href'));
        var topOffset = $section.offset().top;

        // Adjust extra offset if not primary section 
        if(!$section.parent('#wrapper').length){
            topOffset = topOffset - 0;
        }

        // Scroll page
        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: topOffset
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');

    });

/***************************************************
        SCROLLING
***************************************************/
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

        var scrollOffset = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

        if(scrollOffset <= 125){
            jQuery('#logo').stop().animate({top: -scrollOffset}, 700);
            jQuery('#main').stop().animate({top: -scrollOffset + 155}, 50);
        }else{
            jQuery('#logo').stop().animate({top: -225}, 50);
            jQuery('#main').stop().animate({top: 0}, 50);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link to your page? - it may be that this is being loaded on initial site visit and when you change pages the content is being loaded via ajax, so the dom elements you are referencing in your jquery do not exist when the function is run on page load.

A possible solution may be to replace your .click  - this line:

```
jQuery('#main a, a.internal, a.da-link,  #menu_nav a, .footer_inner a, #footerinternal').click(function(e){
```

with .on like this:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '#main a, a.internal, a.da-link,  #menu_nav a, .footer_inner a, #footerinternal', function(e){
```

This will make the code run even if the elements dont exist within the document body when your jquery is run initially.

I've not spent a lot of time with wordpress so this is a bit of a stab in the dark

Comment: thank you for trying to solve this, i do not have a link i can give you as its not a live site yet. I have already give the .on function and unfortunately didnt work. There is no ajax being loaded so should not be a conflict regarding this. The funny thing is, its just firefox i am having trouble with.

Comment: I think without the page in front of me, all I can suggest is get in firebug and put some breakpoints in your js to trace what's happening., find out what the dom looks like when the js is run and check the elements are defined at the point the code is run.